# Simplifying flags when filtering models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a user model that has a set of notifications:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    # Notification flags
    send_to_all = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    send_to_me = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    send_to_friends = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # ...
```

I am passing them from front-end to my views where I trigger **send_notifications** function.

```
    # ...

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        send_notifications(request.data.get('send_to_all', False))

    # ...
```

And in the **send_notifications** I want to query User.objects.filter() and inlcude only those that have the flag passed from front-end set to True.

My question is:

Is there any way to simplify it? I am asking because there is many notifications options, like 20. And currently my code has 20 ifs:

```
def send_notifications(flag):
    if flag == 'send_to_all':
       users_to_send = User.objects.filter(send_to_all=True) 
    if flag == 'send_to_me':
       users_to_send = User.objects.filter(send_to_me=True) 
    if flag == 'send_to_friends':
       users_to_send = User.objects.filter(send_to_friends=True) 
    if flag == 'another_send_flag':
       users_to_send = User.objects.filter(another_send_flag=True) 
    if flag == 'another_send_flag':
       users_to_send = User.objects.filter(another_send_flag=True)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap `User.objects.filter()` with **eval** like that:

```
users_to_send = eval(f"User.objects.filter({flag}=True)")
```

Comment: This is genius. I found eval() when searching for the answer but didn't know it can be used like this. Thank you"